# How to merge 2 Arrays by comparing two different objects having same values ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

I have 2 Arrays named "onGoingBookings" and "sortedMSArray" . I want to inject / merge sortedMSArray (status key only) to onGoingBooings Array (main Array) when both booking id values are same.

### Response of OngoingBookings

```
{
        addrLine1 = "Al Thanyah Fifth, Dubai, United Arab Emirates";
        addrLine2 = "  ";
        amount = "";
        apntDate = "2017-12-11";
        apntDt = "2017-12-11 11:48:18";
        apntTime = "11:48 am";
        apptLat = "25.071571350098";
        apptLong = "55.14294052124";
        bid = 374;
        bookType = 1;
        cancelAmount = 30;
        "cancel_reason" = "";
        "cat_name" = "Car Wash";
        "dispute_msg" = "";
        disputed = "";
        dt = 20171211114818;
        email = "dev@ios.com";
        fdata =         {
        };
        fname = Apple;
        lname = Mob;
        notes = "";
        pPic = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/iserve/ProfileImages/dev@ios.com2017-11-2711:34:26.jpg";
        phone = 561462146;
        pid = 48;
        "star_rating" = 0;
        statCode = 6;
        status = "Job started.";
    },
        {
        addrLine1 = "Al Thanyah Fifth, Dubai, United Arab Emirates";
        addrLine2 = "  ";
        amount = "";
        apntDate = "2017-12-06";
        apntDt = "2017-12-06 19:29:14";
        apntTime = "07:29 pm";
        apptLat = "25.071369171143";
        apptLong = "55.143840789795";
        bid = 354;
        bookType = 2;
        cancelAmount = 50;
        "cancel_reason" = "";
        "cat_name" = Plumbing;
        "dispute_msg" = "";
        disputed = "";
        dt = 20171206192914;
        email = "";
        fdata =         {
        };
        fname = "";
        lname = "";
        notes = "";
        pPic = "";
        phone = "";
        pid = "";
        "star_rating" = 0;
        statCode = 1;
        status = "Job Pending";
    },
        {
        addrLine1 = "Al Thanyah Fifth, Dubai, United Arab Emirates";
        addrLine2 = "  ";
        amount = "";
        apntDate = "2017-12-06";
        apntDt = "2017-12-06 19:24:12";
        apntTime = "07:24 pm";
        apptLat = "25.071369171143";
        apptLong = "55.143840789795";
        bid = 353;
        bookType = 1;
        cancelAmount = 30;
        "cancel_reason" = "";
        "cat_name" = "Car Wash";
        "dispute_msg" = "";
        disputed = "";
        dt = 20171206192412;
        email = "";
        fdata =         {
        };
        fname = "";
        lname = "";
        notes = "";
        pPic = "";
        phone = "";
        pid = "";
        "star_rating" = 0;
        statCode = 1;
        status = "Job Pending";
    },
```

### Response of sortedMSArray

```
 {
        bookingid = 325;
        status = 1;
    },
        {
        bookingid = 333;
        status = 3;
    },
        {
        bookingid = 374;
        status = 3;
    }
```

### I need Following Solution

Step 1 - compare both array by using @"bid"(ongoingbookings) and @"bookingid"(sortedMSArray)
Step 2 - merge the status key when both booking ids are same.

Please post a code snipped according to my code and response.

### Reference Codes

```
if(requestType == RequestTypeGetAllApptDetails)
            {
                if(pageIndex == 0)
                {
                    pastBookings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    onGoingBookings = response[@"ongoing_appts"];
                    NSLog(@"CHECKINGFAST%@",onGoingBookings);
                }

                [pastBookings addObjectsFromArray:response[@"past_appts"]];
                self.tableView.backgroundView = self.messageView;
                [self.tableView reloadData];


            }
            else if(requestType == RequestTypeGetReportMaterialStatus)
            { // NSArray *custStatusTempArray = response;
                customerStatusArray = response;
                customerstatusDict = response[@"customerstatus"];
                NSLog(@"CUSTOMERSTATUSARRAY %@", customerStatusArray);
                 NSLog(@"CUSTOMERSTATUSDICT %@", customerstatusDict);

               if(customerStatusArray == nil || [customerStatusArray count]==0)
               {
                   NSLog(@"NO MATERIAL ACCEPTED");
               }
                else
                {
                     custStatusFilteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                    if([customerstatusDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                    {
                        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)customerstatusDict;
                        [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                            [custStatusFilteredArray addObject:obj];
                            NSLog(@"FILTEREDARRAY%@",custStatusFilteredArray);

                        }];

                    }

                    materialStatusStringArray = [custStatusFilteredArray copy];
                    NSLog(@"materialStatusStringarray%@",materialStatusStringArray);
                    //sorting the materialstatus string array
                    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"bookingid" ascending:NO];
                    sortedMSArray = [materialStatusStringArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
                    NSLog(@"Sorted Array Response -%@", sortedMSArray);
```

Comment: use predicate to get the match of booking id from the main array, and then you can add/update the key-value pairs in the dictionary you get, and replace it back in the main array.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri if possible can you post a sample code in the answer ?

Comment: You can use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` (or `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` if theses id are not unique) to get the index. But there are missing infos: What's the kind of object in your dict? Class of `bid` value and `booingid`? Seems to be from JSON, why keeping NSDictionary (by the way there are not mutable?) and not using custom object?

Comment: @Larme it is a form of json but fetched from socket.io in my dictionary I just added the whole array for filtering purpuses onnly bookingid and bid are INT objects in both array. Any code snippets or example please to understand. I am confused!.